# Result of differntiation evaluates numerically in plotting but not in standalone evaluation

Tags: maxima

The following is my script:

---

```
binom_df(s, N, p):= ( N! / ( s! * (N-s)! ) ) * ( p^s ) * ( 1 - p) ^ ( N-s );

ddn_binom(s, N, p):= diff( binom_df(s, N, p), s);
ddn_binom(s, N, p);

wxplot2d( 
    [ binom_df( s, 100, 1/2 ), ddn_binom( s, 100, 1/2 ) ],
    [s, 30, 70],
    [ box, false ],
    [ legend, "N=100, p= 1/2",
        "diff( binom_df( s, N, p ) )"
    ],
    [ xlabel, "s"]
);

for s: 1 thru 10 step 1 do (
    display(s),
    pr_val: ev( ( ddn_binom( s1, N1, p1 ) ), s1=s, N1=100, p1=0.5 ),
    display(pr_val)
);

ddn_binom( 10, 100, 1/10 );
```

---

The call to `ddn_binom` works in `wxplot2d`; I get the graph. But the call to `ddn_binom` in the 'for' loop fails with the message:

```
diff: second argument must be a variable; found 1
```

which is the reason I have the last line with constant arguments
but it too fails with the message:

```
diff: second argument must be a variable; found 10
```

I am not conversant with the basic principles of how `Maxima` works.
If you can help me, I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

BD

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that the loop variable should be s1 and not s. That did fix the loop but the call : ddn_binom( 10, 100, 1/10 ); still gives me the same error.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment- I'm flailing about and have this confused. The original question is good.

Answer (score 3):

```
 (%i1) binom_df(s, N, p):= ( N! / ( s! * (N-s)! ) ) * ( p^s ) * ( 1 - p) ^ ( N-s ) $
 (%i2) ddn_binom1(s, N, p):= diff(binom_df(s, N, p), s) $
```

In `(%i2)` the function body is not evaluated. It is
evaluated every time the function `ddn_binom1` is called with the
formal argument `s` assigned to an actual argument. `diff` fails if `s` is a number.

You can use `define` if you want the body evaluated

```
(%i3) define(ddn_binom2(s, N, p), diff(binom_df(s, N, p), s)) $
```

`fundef` returns the function definitions:

```
 (%i4) display2d: false $
 (%i5) fundef(ddn_binom1);
 (%o5) ddn_binom1(s,N,p):=diff(binom_df(s,N,p),s)
 (%i6) fundef(ddn_binom2);
 (%o6) ddn_binom2(s,N,p):=(-(N!*(1-p)^(N-s)*p^s*psi[0](s+1))/((N-s)!*s!))
                  +(N!*(1-p)^(N-s)*p^s*psi[0]((-s)+N+1))/((N-s)!*s!)
          -(N!*log(1-p)*(1-p)^(N-s)*p^s)/((N-s)!*s!)
          +(N!*(1-p)^(N-s)*p^s*log(p))/((N-s)!*s!)
```

Links to the documentation: [operator :=](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_7.html#IDX232), [define](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_36.html#define), [fundef](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_36.html#fundef)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the variable s in your loop, because it's used in function.

You can first get a function and then evaulate:

```
for t: 1 thru 10 step 1 do (
    display(t),
    pr_val: ddn_binom( s1, 100, 0.5 ),
    pr_val:ev(pr_val,s1=t),
    display(pr_val)
);
```

You can also use subst:

```
for t: 1 thru 10 step 1 do (
    display(t),
    pr_val: subst(t,s1,ddn_binom( s1, 100, 0.5 )),
    display(pr_val)
);
```

Comment: Thank you Michael; that was very helpful.

I understand the substitution as a solution, but this proves that there is a difference in the internal representation of a function defined directly (binom_df) and one defined indirectly (ddn_binom) through the symbolic differentiation.

If there is a document that would help understand why and when to expect this behaviour, I would appreciate it.

Once again, thanks.

BD